# Handle QTabletEvents inside QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to handle QTabletEvents inside a QWebView. The tricky part is that I need to handle these events in JavaScript:

```
canvas.on("mousemove", function () {
    // check if pen was used using PyQt!
}
```

as well as in PyQt in order to detect if the event was triggered by a pen (instead of a mouse):

```
def tabletEvent(self, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.TabletMove:
        event.accept()
        print("Pen used!")
        // get this info back to javascript
```

Is it possible to somehow get both working together?

Comment: [evaluateJavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript).

Comment: Thanks, but how would that help me in this specific case?

Comment: When the tablet event occurs, call a javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView

html = """
<html>
<body>
    <h1><button onmousedown="foo()">Push me!</button></h1>
</body>

<script>
    function foo() {
        if(penDetector.isPenUsed()){
            alert("Booya!");
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
"""


class TestView(QWebView):
    class PenDetector(QObject):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.penUsed = False

        @pyqtSlot(result=bool)
        def isPenUsed(self):
            return self.penUsed

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.penDetector = self.PenDetector()
        self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("penDetector", self.penDetector)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.penDetector.penUsed = False
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def tabletEvent(self, event):
        self.penDetector.penUsed = True
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TestView()
    frame = view.page().mainFrame()
    view.setHtml(html)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```